# Get results of three queries into one table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the situation,

I have an interface with a dropdown(All, Category, Category type, Product) and search button. There are three database tables for each section as CATEGORY, CATEGORYTYPE and PRODUCT
When user select the `All` option search, I am getting results from all three tables and display on a HTML table.

TO do pagination, I want to fetch results set by set from all the tables.

Here are the three queries I'm using:

```
SELECT CATNAME,CATDESC,CATSTATUS FROM CATEGORY WHERE CATNAME like %a%

SELECT CATTYPENAME,CATTYPEDESC,CATTYPESTATUS FROM CATEGORYTYPE WHERE CATTYPENAME like %a%

SELECT PRODUCTNAME,PRODUCTDESC,PRODUCTSTATUS FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTNAME like %a%
```

From all the tables I'm only fetching the same set of column I want to combine the three queries. I hope my question is understandable. This is not about joining the three tables.. I want the results from all three queries to act as a one set or records and paginate them.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and please ask if the question is not clear.

The application is JAVA EE based. Struts used and DB is MySQL.

Comment: You could create a view in MySQL that uses union to merge the data from the three tables. If I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @esranga: you mean at the time I enter data to those tables? or at the times im gonna do this fetching?

Comment: You use the view to get your data when the user has selected "All".

Comment: When should I generate the view?

Comment: You create the view in the same way that you create a table. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 1):

Using view u can do what you want.
in very first u have to change columns heading as same. like

```
SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS FROM CATEGORY WHERE NAME like %a%
SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS FROM CATEGORYTYPE WHERE NAME like %a%
SELECT NAME,DESCRIPTION,STATUS FROM PRODUCT WHERE NAME like %a%
```

then you can create view like this

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT *
FROM ((CATEGORY NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN CATEGORYTYPE)
    NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN PRODUCT);
```

**P.S. if you can not change columns heading,you can have to change view according to that tables' columns**